# Could you help me translate this sentence? < 今更、咎められることなんて恐ろしくもない。>

Tags: translation, meaning, adjectives, passive-voice

I'm not really getting the meaning of this. Is it "At this point getting suspected is not even scary"?

> 今更、咎められることなんて恐ろしくもない。

I would be grateful if someone could help me :]

Comment: (Google.Translate) ----->  [ Too late, there is no horribly My God to be blamed. ] ------ I guess we still need human translators. ------- Babelfish Translation  ------>  [ Nothing scary is that you now have to be blamed. ]  <--- this is better, but we'd still need human translators.

Comment: Please put your translation here, even if it's totally wrong. I'm sure it's better than an automatic translation!

Comment: See, it's waaay better than these machine translations :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 今更、咎められることなんて恐ろしくもない。
>
> "At this point,  getting suspected is not even scary."

That's good. It may even be perfect.

今更、<-- maybe because this person has been accused before ?

恐ろしくない === I'm not afraid of ...

恐ろしくもない === I'm not even afraid of ... (も for emphasis)

A better translation may be [... the thought of being accused doesn't make me afraid in the least.]

Or maybe she's already being (or starting to be) accused, in which case:

> After what I've been through, being accused means nothing.

... doesn't scare me none.